# The graph (for ideal gas) between(-T)(dV/dP) and (V^2) for adiabatic process is?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, differentiation, adiabatic

Where P stands for Pressure, V is Volume and T is temperature. Please explain me from the beginning.

Comment: $PV^{\gamma}$ is constant for an adiabatic process. You have to differentiate that equation to get the answer.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that we don't answer homework or worked example type questions. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework/exercise questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).